# Is there a service available in Azure to migrate MS Access 32-bit db and it's artifacts?

Tags: sql-server, azure, ms-access

The objective is to migrate the tables and other artifacts in a 32-bit MS Access DB to Azure Cloud? Is there any service available in Azure which can integrate with 32-bit Access?

Comment: Nope, those should have been migrated to SQL Server like 15 years ago. Do it now, then you can move from there using SQL Server tools.

Comment: And the forms, code and reports? - how does moving data to SQL server help the application part? Perhaps you suggesting to move just the data - as migrating now or 15 years ago would not help replace the Access UI.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect to your Azure SQL database using SSMS on your local machine, you should be able to use the Import / Export Wizard in SSMS to load the Access data into Azure.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way to convert other artifacts in Access like reports and procedures to Azure SQL?

Comment: Reports are not an SQL artifact.  Access is an application development environment and a database; SQL Server is "just" a database.

Answer (score 2):

That tool is the [SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access (AccessToSQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/access/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-access-accesstosql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Is there a way to convert other artifacts in Access like reports and
> procedures to Azure SQL?

Nope. It is about data only. All other objects live in Access. Reports may be recreated using *Reporting Services*, but no conversion exists.